# Negate matched results of regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to come out with a regex expression that negate the matched results of regex expression: `.google.*search`. And, is it possible to achieve it with regex from the regex expression I am trying to negate?

**Test data**

```
[1] https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk02MzEfbUp3jO4Np
[2] https://github.com/redis/redis-rb
[3] https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

**Expected result**

Row 2, 3 match the regex pattern and are part of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/a2TuU1/2) does the trick

```
^(?!.+google.*search)
```

basically matching the beginning of the line then negating `(?!)` (negative lookahead) your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a negative lookahead here:

```
https?:\/\/(?!.*\.google\..*search).*
```

### Demo

The "secret sauce" here is `(?!.*\.google\..*search)`, which asserts that `.google.` followed by `search` does not occur anywhere within the URL to the right of the `https://` portion.